# Typing in one entry causes all entries to be written into (Tkinter)

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter

I'm creating a sudoku solver desktop application with a GUI using Tkinter. The issue I'm having is when it comes to inputting the board.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
N = 9
input = [["0" for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        new_col = int(j/3)
        new_row = int(i/3)
        if (-1)**(new_col+new_row) == 1:
            colour = "lightgrey"
        else:
            colour = "white"
        entry = Entry(root, width=10, bg=colour, textvariable=input[i][j])
        entry.grid(row=i, column=j)
set_button = Button(root, text="Set", command=set, padx=20, pady=10).grid(row=10,column=3, columnspan=3)
```

The set button is used to set the values and then display the actual board.
The issue I'm having is that typing in any one of the boxes causes the same value to be typed into every other box. I don't understand how this is happening. Is my array declaration at fault maybe?
Also, I checked and the array is unchanged even after clicking set.

Comment: First of all, the `textvariable` parameter must be a `tkinter.StringVar()` not a basic python `str`. Second of all, why not put the entries in the array? You can use `<tkinter.Entry>.get()` to get the user's input, `<tkinter.Entry>.delete(0, "end")` to clear the entry, and `<tkinter.Entry>.insert("end", <text>)` to insert text to the end of the entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
entry = Entry(root, width=10, bg=colour, textvariable=input[i][j])
```

Because of the way you've initialized `input`, the above code is the same as this:

```
entry = Entry(root, width=10, bg=colour, textvariable="0")
```

Thus, all widgets have the same value for `textvariable` so they are all linked together and share the same memory for the value.

Each entry needs a unique `textvariable`, and the value of that option needs to be a tkinter variable object such as `StringVar`.

That being said, you rarely need to use `textvariable`. Since you aren't adding a trace to the variables, they are largely unnecessary. I recommend you remove the `textvariable` and instead save your entry in your array. You can then call the `get` method of the entry to get the value.